# Let $f(z) = \frac{2z-1}{3z+2}$. Prove that $ \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(z_0+h)-f(z_0)}{h} = \frac{7}{(3z_0+2)^2}$

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

I'm having a hard time with the problem stated. I understand this is an epsilon-delta proof. However, When I get to simplifying the numerator, I get $\frac{7h}{9z(z+h)+6(2z+h)+4}$ (this is through combining fractions by giving them a common denominator). My goal is to be able to factor out an $h$ so that I could cancel it with the denominator, and move from there, but once I do that I still am unsure of how to proceed with this epsilon-delta proof.

Comment: I got over the hump of factoring out the denominator (by division rules, it automatically would cancel out the h, and leave $\frac{7}{9z(z+h)+6(2z+h)+4}$. Now I'm a tad stuck on how to continue.

Comment: Actually, at this point. If I just substituted in 0 for $h$, then the bottom would factor into $(3z+2)^2$... which is the answer. That isn't sufficient though right? That's just me evaluating the limit, whereas I want to prove it, yes?

Comment: To prove that $A=\frac{7}{(3z_0+2)^2}$ is the limit of $B=\frac{f(z_0+h)-f(z_0)}{h}$ when $h \rightarrow 0$ you must show that for any $\epsilon > 0$ and $h_0: |h_0-0|<\epsilon$ the difference $|A-B(z_0,h_0)|$ can be majored by proper choice of $\delta > 0$: $|A-B|<\delta$. Rewrite the difference then try to pick a proper majorant $\delta$ functionally dependent on $\epsilon$ (and probably on $z_0$).

Comment: @mbaitoff, is this the right approach: If $\delta \leq 1$, then $0 < |h| < \delta$ implies $|\frac{7}{9z(z+h)+6(2z+h)+4}| = |\frac{7}{h(9z+6) + z(9z+12)+4}| = \frac{|7|}{|h(9z+6) + z(9z+12)+4|} \leq \frac{|7|}{|h||9z+6| + |z||9z+12|+|4|} \leq \frac{7}{\delta |9z+6| + |z||9z+12| + 4}$. Taking $\delta$ as the smaller of $1$ and $\frac{\frac{7}{\epsilon}-4-|z||9z+12|}{|9z+6|}$, the require result follows.

Comment: @mbaitoff, to show the existence of this limit and what it is equal to by the $\;\epsilon-\delta\;$ definition may be a little too messy **if** we already have arithmetic of limits to our disposal...

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{f(z+h)-f(z)}h=\frac{\frac{2(z+h)-1}{3(z+h)+2}-\frac{2z-1}{3z+2}}{h}=\frac{(2(z+h)-1)(3z+2)-(2z-1)(3(z+h)+2)}{(3z+2)(3(z+h)+2)h}$$

$$=\frac{\left[(2z+2h-1)(3z+2)\right]-\left[(2z-1)(3z+3h+2)\right]}{(3z+2)(3z+3h+2)h}=$$

$$=\frac{7\rlap{/}{\color{red}h}}{(3z+2)(3z+3h+2)\rlap{/}{\color{red}h}}\stackrel{\text{arithmetic of limits}}{\xrightarrow[h\to 0]{}}\frac7{(3z+2)^2}$$

Comment: Don, I know how to evaluate this limit, but wouldn't the proof require me to use epsilon and delta?

Comment: Not at all @David , since if you already worked *and* proved the different aspects of arithmetic of limits then you can use them freely.

Comment: Don, if you allow using the arithmetics of limits, you could just have used it in the first place, substituting $h=0$ into limit expression due to the contunuity of it at $h=0$.

Comment: Ah. Is this to say that a sufficient proof is working through the arithmetic and coming through with the answer? Alright. However, does what I wrote in the comments (of this question, not your answer) follow?

Comment: Of course not, @mbaitoff : just try to do it and you'll get an undefined expression $\;\frac 00\;$ !

Comment: Well yes, @David : if you want to go by first principles/definition, then you'll have to go $\;\epsilon-\delta\;$ ...which seems a little odd in this case since that assumes you *already* know (divine inspiration or anyhow) what the limit is.

Comment: @DonAntonio, I believe that is what the question wants. As the question reads, I am to prove that the limit is $\frac{7}{(3z_0+2)^2}$, which one could say is my divine inspiration (heh). My results (in the comments above) are messy though for $\delta$ in respect to $\epsilon$ and $z$, so I'm unsure if I did that correctly.

Comment: Well, then yes @David : $\;\epsilon-\delta\;$ it is.